# Is there a term to describe the tendency to do what's minimum?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, nouns, terminology

I will try my best to describe. Some times, I have found that people tend to do the minimum procedures to finish what they do, and find improving unnecessary. I understand different people have different definition of what's perfect, and have justification for not making it better. Maybe it is due to rules in where they live, or policies in where they work, or just because we are not paid enough to polish the result. Is there a word or phrase to describe this phenomenon? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [A very similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165550/what-do-you-call-a-person-that-only-do-the-minimum-to-get-through-day-to-day-bas) came up recently. Does that help?

Comment: @Andrew Leach, thanks for pointing that out, I can see there are words that describe the individuals, is there a word that describes their behavior?

Comment: @Andrew Leach, +1, found a lot of information researching the post you sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perfunctory - (adjective)
(of an action or gesture) carried out with a minimum of effort or reflection.

http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=perfunctory

Comment: My link may not work because I use the mobile version and it is of no good help. Google the word or look it in wikitionary.