# Is there a word for "doing the bare minimum out of the maximum that could have been done"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word or idiom that would explain a situation where one has ended up doing the bare required minimum out of the maximum that could have been done.

Think of it as a person realizing the minimum (but still acceptable amount) of their potential.

For example "goldilocks" is a word explaining "the exact right amount", is there something similar for the above?

Comment: Doing the bare minimum *means* “doing the bare minimum out of the maximum that could have been done”.

Comment: It's called "doing the bare minimum".  "Bare minimum" is fairly idiomatic in this sense.

Comment: If you do not want your Q closed down for off-topic you _must_ provide a sample sentence demonstrating usage of the target language.

Comment: It depends. Is someone else now left to do the remainder, or isn't there any remainder because they were clever. "I will always choose a lazy person to do a difficult job because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it." - Bill Gates

Comment: Do you mean the bare minimum to do the job adequately (everything done but no extras/no bonuses/nothing supererogatory/getting a grade that's just what you need), or the bare minimum to avoid getting fired (half-assing a task, covering up your mistakes, and hoping nobody looks too closely)? I think there are various terms in this area with different connotations (good, bad, indifferent) and different degrees of politeness.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum (synonym "least")

As a phrase/idiom, you could use "**get by**" and/or "**skin of one's teeth**" meaning "**barely**" as a single word.

> You did just enough to **get by**. he got paid by the **skin of his
>   teeth**. That's **barely** passable in my mind.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+by

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/skin+of+one%27s+teeth

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/barely

Answer (score 0):

A [Jobsworth](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jobsworth), is somebody who apparently takes great pleasure in not only doing themselves only what is specifically required, but in most cases only allowing others to also.

[The 'Computer says no' sketches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_says_no) work on the frustration felt by people having to deal with people who lack any and all initiative or ability to work beyond the scope explicit instructions.

Other types of people, or at least descriptions of them, are covered in [English:SE 'Please give me derogatory terms to apply to my co-workers'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165550/what-do-you-call-a-person-that-only-do-the-minimum-to-get-through-day-to-day-bas)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [adequate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adequate). From MW:

> **[adequate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adequate)** 
>   adjective 
>   1. sufficient for a specific need or requirement 
>   ...
>   of a quality that is acceptable but not better than acceptable 
>   *Her first performance was merely adequate.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Quiet quitting you mean?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coast) definition 2c...

> **coast**
> to proceed easily without special application of effort or concern
> *coasted through school*
> —often used with on
> *a company coasting on its good reputation*

The original *literal* meaning as a verb was (of a ship) was *to sail keeping close to the coastline*. I don't know how it was extended to *taking a moving powered vehicle out of gear* (so it only keeps moving through *momentum* - illegal in the UK beyond a very short distance). But it's the ***without engine power*** sense that's further extended metaphorically to many contexts where (often, *limited*) progress occurs with the subject making little or no effort.

I think the second cited usage above *exactly* matches OP's context.